# Filtering association to fetch full category tree via API

Tags: shopware6-api

I have two test categories setup in my Shopware 6 demo:

| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Construction | Doorframe | - |
| Doorframe | Doorframe | Doorframe |

(All five elements have distinct IDs.)

I want to fetch (for syncing) the full tree of `Construction -> Doorframe`. To make sure I'm not fetching the wrong category from a different parent category, I am filtering on the levels and the (nested) parents.

In words: "Give me a **Doorframe** category from **level 2** that has a **parent** named
**Construction** on **level 1**".

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 5,
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "multi",
            "operator": "and",
            "queries": [
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "level",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "name",
                    "value": "Doorframe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sort": [],
    "post-filter": [],
    "associations": {
        "parent": {
            "limit": 2,
            "fields": [],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "type": "multi",
                    "operator": "and",
                    "queries": [
                        {
                            "type": "equals",
                            "field": "level",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "equals",
                            "field": "name",
                            "value": "Construction"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "association": null
        }
    },
    "aggregations": [],
    "grouping": [],
    "includes": [],
    "fields": [],
    "total-count-mode": true
}
```

What I don't understand is the result I'm getting.

First result is `Doorframe -> Doorframe` and the second result is `Construction -> Doorframe`.

It's like ignoring the nested query that filters for `Construction on level 1`. I'd expect only one result with that query.

```
Response:
Array
(
    [total] => 2
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [extensions] => Array
                        (
                            [foreignKeys] => Array
                                (
                                    [extensions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [apiAlias] => category_foreign_keys_extension
                                )

                            [search] => Array
                                (
                                    [extensions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_uniqueIdentifier] =>
                                    [translated] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [autoIncrement] => 16
                                )

                        )

                    [_uniqueIdentifier] => 0189deafebbc7196a49203ec748d7049
                    [versionId] => 0fa91ce3e96a4bc2be4bd9ce752c3425
                    [translated] => Array
                        (
                            [breadcrumb] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Doorframe
                                    [1] => Doorframe
                                )

                            [name] => Doorframe
                            [customFields] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [slotConfig] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [linkType] =>
                            [internalLink] =>
                            [externalLink] =>
                            [linkNewTab] =>
                            [description] =>
                            [metaTitle] =>
                            [metaDescription] =>
                            [keywords] =>
                        )

                    [createdAt] => 2023-08-10T09:03:39.599+00:00
                    [updatedAt] => 2023-08-10T09:03:49.434+00:00
                    [afterCategoryId] =>
                    [parentId] => 0189deafb9317c8594ef49c00aaf41c0
                    [autoIncrement] => 16
                    [mediaId] =>
                    [name] => Doorframe
                    [breadcrumb] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Doorframe
                            [1] => Doorframe
                        )

                    [path] => |0189deafb9317c8594ef49c00aaf41c0|
                    [level] => 2
                    [active] =>
                    [childCount] => 2
                    [visibleChildCount] => 0
                    [displayNestedProducts] => 1
                    [parent] =>
                    [children] =>
                    [translations] =>
                    [media] =>
                    [products] =>
                    [nestedProducts] =>
                    [tags] =>
                    [cmsPageId] => 0189d01a0e8d7360b0aa1e8208c66c99
                    [cmsPageIdSwitched] => 1
                    [cmsPage] =>
                    [productStreamId] =>
                    [productStream] =>
                    [slotConfig] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [navigationSalesChannels] =>
                    [footerSalesChannels] =>
                    [serviceSalesChannels] =>
                    [linkType] =>
                    [linkNewTab] =>
                    [internalLink] =>
                    [externalLink] =>
                    [visible] => 1
                    [type] => page
                    [productAssignmentType] => product
                    [description] =>
                    [metaTitle] =>
                    [metaDescription] =>
                    [keywords] =>
                    [mainCategories] =>
                    [seoUrls] =>
                    [customEntityTypeId] =>
                    [customFields] =>
                    [id] => 0189deafebbc7196a49203ec748d7049
                    [apiAlias] => category
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [extensions] => Array
                        (
                            [foreignKeys] => Array
                                (
                                    [extensions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [apiAlias] => category_foreign_keys_extension
                                )

                            [search] => Array
                                (
                                    [extensions] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_uniqueIdentifier] =>
                                    [translated] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [autoIncrement] => 27
                                )

                        )

                    [_uniqueIdentifier] => 0189dfe99b127e24bb25bf27a49a9c6d
                    [versionId] => 0fa91ce3e96a4bc2be4bd9ce752c3425
                    [translated] => Array
                        (
                            [breadcrumb] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Construction
                                    [1] => Doorframe
                                )

                            [name] => Doorframe
                            [customFields] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [slotConfig] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [linkType] =>
                            [internalLink] =>
                            [externalLink] =>
                            [linkNewTab] =>
                            [description] =>
                            [metaTitle] =>
                            [metaDescription] =>
                            [keywords] =>
                        )

                    [createdAt] => 2023-08-10T14:46:18.363+00:00
                    [updatedAt] => 2023-08-10T14:46:25.790+00:00
                    [afterCategoryId] =>
                    [parentId] => 0189dfe9201b7b8dba56909d2343c99d
                    [autoIncrement] => 27
                    [mediaId] =>
                    [name] => Doorframe
                    [breadcrumb] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Construction
                            [1] => Doorframe
                        )

                    [path] => |0189dfe9201b7b8dba56909d2343c99d|
                    [level] => 2
                    [active] => 1
                    [childCount] => 0
                    [visibleChildCount] => 0
                    [displayNestedProducts] => 1
                    [parent] =>
                    [children] =>
                    [translations] =>
                    [media] =>
                    [products] =>
                    [nestedProducts] =>
                    [tags] =>
                    [cmsPageId] => 0189d01a0e8d7360b0aa1e8208c66c99
                    [cmsPageIdSwitched] => 1
                    [cmsPage] =>
                    [productStreamId] =>
                    [productStream] =>
                    [slotConfig] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [navigationSalesChannels] =>
                    [footerSalesChannels] =>
                    [serviceSalesChannels] =>
                    [linkType] =>
                    [linkNewTab] =>
                    [internalLink] =>
                    [externalLink] =>
                    [visible] => 1
                    [type] => page
                    [productAssignmentType] => product
                    [description] =>
                    [metaTitle] =>
                    [metaDescription] =>
                    [keywords] =>
                    [mainCategories] =>
                    [seoUrls] =>
                    [customEntityTypeId] =>
                    [customFields] =>
                    [id] => 0189dfe99b127e24bb25bf27a49a9c6d
                    [apiAlias] => category
                )

        )

    [aggregations] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The reference at https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria made me think putting `filter` into `association` would work.

Trying without nesting, but connecting the filter via dot-notation (e.g. `parent.level`, `parent.level` or even deeper, `parent.parent.parent.level`, ...) seems to work.

All filters are now in the root `filter` and the nested `filter` is empty.

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "multi",
            "operator": "and",
            "queries": [
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "level",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "name",
                    "value": "Doorframe"
                },
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "parent.level",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "type": "equals",
                    "field": "parent.name",
                    "value": "Construction"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sort": [],
    "post-filter": [],
    "associations": {
        "parent": {
            "limit": 10,
            "fields": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "level",
                "path",
                "parent",
                "breadcrumb"
            ],
            "includes": [],
            "filter": [],
            "association": null
        }
    },
    "aggregations": [],
    "grouping": [],
    "includes": [],
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "level",
        "path",
        "parent",
        "breadcrumb"
    ],
    "total-count-mode": true
}
```